# Problem with missing yum package CentOS (Virtualmin)

Tags: centos, yum, webmin

I am struggling with installation of `rh-php71` package using yum on CentOS 6.10 and wondering how I could debug what's the root cause.

I have followed instructions on [scl](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-php71/):

```
# 1. Install a package with repository for your system:
# On CentOS, install package centos-release-scl available in CentOS repository:
$ sudo yum install centos-release-scl

# On RHEL, enable RHSCL repository for you system:
$ sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms

# 2. Install the collection:
$ sudo yum install rh-php71
```

However 2nd step gives me output:

```
No package rh-php71 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

What I've tried is:

```
yum clean all && yum makecache
```

But package is not found.

I have already `rh-php70` installed from scl:

```
$ yum info rh-php70.x86_64
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirrors.ovh.net
 * centos-sclo-rh: centos.mirrors.ovh.net
 * centos-sclo-sclo: centos.mirror.ate.info
 * epel: mirror.freethought-internet.co.uk
 * extras: centos.mirrors.ovh.net
 * remi-php71: remi.mirror.ate.info
 * remi-safe: remi.mirror.ate.info
 * updates: mirrors.ircam.fr
Installed Packages
Name        : rh-php70
[...]
From repo   : centos-sclo-rh
[...]
```

Would appreciate help how I could figure out the root cause. Thank you for your time and suggestions

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the PHP 7.1 software collection is not built for CentOS 6, but is available in CentOS 7.

You could try to rebuild the `rh-php71` software collection for CentOS 6, but I have not found any information that anyone has tried to do that.

You can find information about available software collections from [their website](https://www.softwarecollections.org) or from the configured [YUM repository](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/sclo/x86_64/rh/)

Comment: I see. So the best way is to `cat /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-SCLo-scl-rh.repo | grep http`, follow link and broswe available packages, right?

Comment: That would show you what is available to you from the software collections, `yum search` can do similar work when the repository is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

When looking for the correct package to install into a CentOS system, the first place I tend to look is under centos.pkgs.org.  Their search comes up with mostly exhaustive results for the major .rpm repositories out there as well as instructions on how to install each package on the relevant page.

[php71 rpm for CentOS 6 (remi repo)](https://centos.pkgs.org/6/remi-x86_64/php71-2.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm.html)

Comment: Thank you for reply. I've tried this one, but there are many missing packages for this dependency (newer versions or glibc and openssl) and no updates found for them. So I think that this is some inconsistency here (no complementary packages).